# Problemas al ordenar cajas con flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

No encuentro la forma correcta de hacer lo de la imagen #1 con flexbox, tengo cajas dinámicas que se agregan como si fuera una lista de posts pero al intentar colocarlas a la izquierda y que mantengan su full-width con todo el contenedor es donde tengo el problema, sabiendo esto hay que tomar en cuenta según la imagen #1:

1. Barra de los 4 lados color rosa: es el padding del contenedor.
2. Barra rosa entre ambas filas: es la separación de ambas.
3. Barra color verde: es la separación entre las cajas.

quiero que se mantenga el full-width de todas las cajas y a la vez que las cajas de abajo sin terminar, se vayan alineando a la izquierda.

Nota: Por favor los otros 3 recuadros marcados en X rojo no es la solución que busco.

[image: problema ordenando cajas con flexbox]

Comment: Aclaro que es necesario mantener el full-width con el tamaño del contenedor, no solo busco alinear a la izquierda

Comment: Si necesitas que se alinee todo tanto en filas y columnas, creo que una mejor opcion seria utilizar CSS Grid

Comment: Usando justify-content: flex-start se deberían de ordenar de derecha a izquierda

Comment: @LuisSandrea lograste resolver el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez utilizar CSS Grid sea mas sencillo si necesitas tener tanto filas como columnas alineadas; si bien puedes lograr un resultado igual con Flexbox, tomaria mas trabajo ya que Flexbox es optimo para layouts de una sola dimension (o filas, o columnas). Con el codigo siguiente deberia ser suficiente para crear un grid de 3x2 sin mucho problema.

Ademas es facilmente ajustable; puedes modificar el espacio entre cada elemento con `grid-gap`, aumentar el `padding`en el contenedor; aumentar el numero de columnas o filas sin preocuparte por afectar elementos individuales.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item item2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item item3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item item4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item item5">Item 5</div>
  <div class="grid-item item6">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahora sí he comprobado, este era la solución que buscaba y que había visto con anterioridad, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Habría ayudado ver tu código. Tuve que inventarlo. Es esto lo que quieres conseguir?

```css
.cajaflex {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px solid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.item {
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  margin: 5%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  height: 25vh;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="cajaflex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lamentablemente no funciona como esperaba fíjate acá http://prntscr.com/mwm52f

Comment: Una imagen no ayuda  Agrega tu código si necesitas ayuda